# Google cache gone and relevant to instant preview

Tags: google-search

Where is Google cached versions of pages?

I saw [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Web+Search/thread?tid=3340c5b01f83f283&hl=en#all) link, that it's within "instant preview" but I can't see instant preview anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover over one result, you should see an arrow block at the right side, as in the picture below:

[image]

Click on it and the preview of the page will open to the right. Then click on the **Cached** link:
[image]

More details on Google's [Web Search Help page](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=1055571).